# Private DHCP through a switch using two eth interfaces?

Tags: centos, dhcp, switch, linux-networking, pxe-boot

Right now, I have an Scientific Linux blade connected to the internet on eth3, and connected to a 48 port Cisco switch on eth2. This Cisco switch is connected to the eth2 of 24 blank blades (which are not connected to the internet).

I want to be able to assign the 24 blades private IPs based on their hostname so my main blade can connect to them, while keeping them fenced off from the internet. However, because there are so many, I also want to install kickstarted CentOS on them via PXE from the main blade. To do this I would need them to be assigned an IP first via DHCP, right?

So how would I go about doing all this? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a basic DHCP/PXE boot environment.

1. Build your PXE Boot resources as per CentOS documentation.
2. Setup DHCP and TFTP on SL.
3. Configure SL DHCP to serve leases with PXE booting options.

The "private" blades will not have access to the internet unless you enable routing etc on the SL blade (1).

There is nothing overly special about what you're doing. You'll need to statically assign a private address to eth2 on the SL blade, then configure the corresponding `subnet` block in `dhcpd.conf`

*(1) Unless SL does something stupid like automatically enabling routing, which I doubt.*

Comment: A quick question to help me understand. When I have two connected interfaces in this way in the SL blade, and I ping an IP address, what governs which interface it will try first?

Comment: That is taken care of by your routing table. To view it, run `ip route show`